# Currently, it continues to run after 1min. I want it stop if the condition is met

Tags: react-native

Below, I want to clearInterval if processingStatus[0] === "DELIVERED".

```js
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchDeliveryStatus({ client_id: user.id }));

    // Fetching data changes after 1 Minute
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch(fetchDeliveryStatus({ client_id: user.id }));
      // nextStep();
    }, 60000);

    if (processingStatus[0] === "DELIVERED") {
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef()`, like this

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
    const processingStatus = useSelector(...);
    const processingStatusRef = useRef(null);
    processingStatusRef.current = processingStatus[0];
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchDeliveryStatus({ client_id: user.id }));

        // Fetching data changes after 1 Minute
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (processingStatusRef.current === "DELIVERED") {
                clearInterval(interval)
            } else {
                dispatch(fetchDeliveryStatus({ client_id: user.id }));
            }
        }, 60000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [dispatch]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Asin. Just to add some context, this is how am using useSelector;
```
const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  const { deliveryStatus } = state;

const processingStatus = deliveryStatus.map(
    (status) => status.delivery_status
  );
```
processingStatus returns an array so I pick the one in the first index [0] hence  processingStatus[0]